spring boot, how to get swagger UI to be under /swagger/ path?
We have a basic spring boot api service which exposes REST endpoints, e.g. https://myservice.com/customer/get and https://myservice.com/country/get
We integrated swagger, but the URLs for swagger are the root.
E.g. https://myservice.com/swagger-ui.html
And all swaggers various resources are also in the root (such as webjars)
As our service is behind a proxy, we need a rule for all swagger resources, such as /swagger/*
Is there any way to get swagger (and its resources) to be served from a specific path, not the root?
This is our SpringFoxConfig.java:
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("OUR-API")
                .description("Our api service endpoints")
                .version("mixed")
                .build();
    }
}

and this is the WebAppConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}

Examples of what resources swagger is serving from root which we need to move to /swagger/ or similar:

Our swagger version (version 3 would not run, so we are using 2.8)
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

We tried adding this to our src/main/resources/application.yml, but it has no effect.  This might be because for this project, application.yml doesnt seem to work.  Is there another way to configure spring projects?
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger-ui:
      path=/swagger

============= UPDATE 1 =====================
Thanks to Mustapha's reply, I tried the following:
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /swagger/api-docs
    swagger-ui:
      base-url: /swagger

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/swagger")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("OUR-API")
                .description("our api service endpoints")
                .version("mixed")
                .build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger/swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}

However, swagger-ui.html still only works on the root (I did a mvn clean before building too), but it does seem to have moved api-docs:


Update your WebAppConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger/swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    }

also your application.properties
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/swagger/api-docs
springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url=/swagger

and SpringFoxConfig
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/swagger")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("OUR-API")
                .description("Our api service endpoints")
                .version("mixed")
                .build();
    }
}


Thanks for the reply, Ive tried this exact config (see update 1 in question), but it only moves api-docs, everything else stays in root.
